# How do I conditionally select a unique value in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been tasked with returning only rows with unique IDs but returning a row for every ID in SQL.  How would I go about this?

Logic:
For primary row, select where JOB_INDICATOR = ‘P’. If there are multiple rows, then use the record where PRIM_ROLE_IND = ‘Y’.  If there are still multiple then select the lowest numbered EMPL_RCD starting at 0.

Example starting point:

| id | name | job | job_indicator | prim_role_ind | empl_rcd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | John Doe | Director | P | N | 0 |
| 1001 | John Doe | Professor | P | Y | 1 |
| 1001 | John Doe | Coach | N | N | 2 |
| 1002 | Bob Jones | Head Janitor | P | Y | 0 |
| 1002 | Bob Jones | Associate Janitor | P | Y | 1 |
| 1003 | Susan Smith | Groundskeeper | P | N | 0 |
| 1003 | Susan Smith | Professor | P | N | 1 |

Desired return:

| id | name | job | job_indicator | prim_role_ind | empl_rcd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | John Doe | Professor | P | Y | 1 |
| 1002 | Bob Jones | Head Janitor | P | Y | 0 |
| 1003 | Susan Smith | Groundskeeper | P | N | 0 |

So far, I have the below, but a new requirement was added to do conditional components.

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE JOB_INDICATOR = 'P'
```

Comment: You can use `row_number() over (partition by id order by job_indicator desc PRIM_ROLE_IND desc EMPL_RCD asc) as rn` in a cte or sub-query. In the main query user `where rn=1` and you should have the rows that you want.

Comment: Thank you!  This gives me a good place to start!

Comment: How would I join to another table in the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to accomplish this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
        SELECT EMPLOYEE.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY 
        prim_role_ind DESC, empl_rcd ASC) as rn
        FROM EMPLOYEE
        WHERE JOB_INDICATOR = 'P'
    ) dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you!  This gives me a good jumping off point!

Comment: How would I join to another table in the same query?